# ui-grid last frozen line thickness

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid and when you freeze/pin columns that last vertical line is slightly darker. I'm wondering how I can alter that line visual so I can make it more obvious? Not really even sure how to phrase the question. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: Anything else I can do to get a "useful" or "accepted" response below?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
.ui-grid-pinned-container.ui-grid-pinned-container-left .ui-grid-header-cell:last-child {
  border-width: 2px;
}
.ui-grid-pinned-container.ui-grid-pinned-container-left .ui-grid-cell:last-child {
  border-width: 2px;
}
.ui-grid-pinned-container.ui-grid-pinned-container-right .ui-grid-header-cell:first-child {
  border-width: 2px;
}
.ui-grid-pinned-container.ui-grid-pinned-container-right .ui-grid-cell:first-child {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Here's a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/gVDydrz12CQIhnZqZ7ij?p=preview.

[image: ui-grid css pin freeze column]

Let me know if you need anything else, or have any other questions.